# This is the dirty price or clean price

Tags: bond

A one year bond of principle 100, coupon 6% with half year paying  and yield 11%. Suppose the beginning day of bond is 1.1 and today is 3.1, then I want to ask that, the price
$$c = \dfrac{3}{e^{0.11 * 0.25}} + \dfrac{103}{e^{0.11 * 0.75}}$$
is the dirty price or clean price?

Comment: What does the beginning day is 1.1 mean?

Comment: @Gordon Jun 1st

Answer (score 0):

It is the dirty price, since it includes accrued interest, as represented by the first part of the equation.

Comment: Where is the accrued interest term, I don't see it. I only see a term for the first half-coupon and a term for the face value plus second half coupon.

Comment: so, the quote in the market is always the clean price i.e this result - accrued interest term?

Comment: And the delivery price is always dirty price in the real trading?